# Implementation of Y-modem protocol in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I want to send a file via serial port and I have to use the Y-modem protocol in Java. I saw the protocol and it looks difficult for me to write it in Java. Any Idea how can I get it easier?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

serialio offers a commercial product..

http://serialio.com/products/jxmodem.php

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

1. Serial port acces from Java: Use RxTx Java library http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
2. Y-Modem Protocol implementation: See this related post [Implementation of X-modem protocol in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606074/implementation-of-x-modem-protocol-in-java)