# Upload file through serial port

Tags: java, file-upload, rxtx

Is there any way how to upload file to embeded device throw Serial port? Im using RXTX, but I thing that I allready only sent data from file, not upload this file. Thanks for advice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws PortInUseException, UnsupportedCommOperationException
{
    java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements())
    {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
        if (portIdentifier.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
            if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned())
            {
                System.out.println("Port is curently used");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open("Zkouska", 2000);
                if (commPort instanceof SerialPort)
                {
                    SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    try
                    {
                        OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                        File file = new File("C:/data/java/RXTX/01_Hello/SerialUploader/uploaddemo.dat");
                        byte[] content = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                        fin.read(content);
                        out.write(content);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                        commPort.close();
                        System.out.println("Tady");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably upload with a filetransfer protocol like

- [ZModem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) (or less popular [XModem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) and [YModem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YMODEM))
- [kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/faq-c-zmo.html) protocol

Have a look here for starters in java: [Implementation of X-modem protocol in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606074/implementation-of-x-modem-protocol-in-java)